# Hovering on "a" elements pushing other away

Tags: html, css, hover

I am practicing on a project and i was styling hyperlinks...but on hovering them each pushes other to side... I cant figure it out why it is happening...and I have done position ,margin and everything that i can do.

```
   .main-nav ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.main-nav ul li{
    padding: 1.2rem;
    list-style: none;
}
.main-nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: #97cb52;
    padding: 1rem;
    
}
```

Comment: remove the padding from a:hover...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Is there a reason that you add padding to the anchor element on hover? For example, did you require the element to get bigger when hovered?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the padding on the "a" tag on hover put the padding on the "a" tag itself.

```
.main-nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.main-nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: #97cb52;
}
```

See this little demo I made: https://jsfiddle.net/64Lfdawb/